# Sympy: How to plot a particular integral function

Tags: sympy

I am a newbie in Sympy programming (on python language).
I need to plot on Jupyter this integral-function to check its qualitative study:

```
F(x) = Integral((ln(1+t**2))/(t*(1+t**2)),(t,0,1/cos(x)))
```

[image]

What is the best way to follow?
I thank you to all for precious help.

A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works well for me:

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import x, t
>>> plot(Integral((ln(1+t**2))/(t*(1+t**2)),(t,0,1/cos(x))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer.Are you sure? we have an integral function where there are [0-1/cos(x)] like bounds. On my study it is different..

Comment: I edited question and answer -- does the equation look right now?

Comment: Yes!It is matching with my study.Thank you very much for code that help me on sympy.The only difference is the x-axis that is on the bottom of the picture :-)

Comment: I tried for exercise to plot the function  Integral((t*ln(abs(2+t)))/((1+t**2)),(t,0,x))'. It seems to go in loop. Do you reach to find ...why Sympy have this behaviour?

Comment: I don't think it likes plotting at the discontinuity at `t=-2` so set the limits accordingly, `plot(Integral((t*ln(abs(2+t)))/((1+t**2)),(t,0,x)),(x,-2,5))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I test the code and it is ok.

Comment: I tested the code and it is ok. My dubt is what is the function diagram from -2 to - infty? I change the limit but It seems that Sympy doesn't like it. On -2, the integral function have a discontinuity point but the integral from 0 to -2 is finite value. So I think that  we can plot the global integral function.What do you think about ?Thanks again for your precious assistance.

Comment: Looks like integration doesn't like to go over the discontinuity. So you would have to manually construct from pieces. `plot(Integral((t*ln(abs(2+t)))/((1+t**2)),(t,0,x)),(x,0,-2))` from 0 to -2 and then `plot(Integral((t*ln(abs(2+t)))/((1+t**2)),(t,-2,x)),(x,-2,-4))` from -2 to -4, for example.

Comment: If it needs to plot into "singular" points what do you think about a "nplot" plot function? Does it exists into Sympy? It can be useful on this similar case with it needs to know what happened in singular point .What do you think about?

Comment: [Davide-sd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2329968/davide-sd) would be a good one to ask about this. I am not certain why the plotting is failing. I thought integrate did not like to go across the discontinuity, but integration over `(t,-3,-1)` works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!Do you suggest me to ask a new question or send the dubt directly as per your previous answer? (In this last case I don't know how to send a direct message from  the site)

Comment: You could either open an issue on the SymPy [issue page](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) or start a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/sympy).